# Create a hue mask in photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I would like to apply some adjustments only on a given hue range, i.e. create a hue mask.

What I have tried is to create a hue mask. I have done some tries, for example I use saturation ajustement layer, changing luminosity and saturation of the different colors, and then use channel mixer or saturation mask. None of the above mothds works for me, especially because I get some artifacts and chunks, which are not visible in the original image.

I have also tried select > color range but it creates some harsh transitions on object contours.

Comment: What bit depth are you working with? Raw or jpeg?

Comment: Raw, rendered to 16 bit RGB

Comment: Would really help if we knew the image your working on. There's lots of different techniques for this and the best one will depend on the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop has an option to convert an image to HSB/HSL under `Filter->Other->HSB/HSL`.

Given the following image:

[image: sample image]

Converting it results in the following hue channel (you'll find it under `Channels->Red`):

[image: hue channel]

This can then be edited into a mask which can be applied to a layer:

[image: mask]

Depending on the original image, more or less fine tuning might be required.

Comment: This is a way indeed. Unfortunately it seems to give poor result in many cases.